# how to disable the browser back button in asp.net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net

How to disable the browser back button in asp.net 4.0 on single or double click of browser?

please respond me quickly.

Comment: please leave my back-button be, i love it. When drinking coffee the `alt-back` combination is unreachable with my short fingers.

Comment: Why do u want to disable it anyway?

Comment: -1 for "please respond me quickly"

Answer (score 2):

asp.net is a server side script and can't change anything in the browser, which is on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it. Becaus this functionality is build in browsers, not in you website. The only way to make a workaround is to open some window without button panels, though this won't help for all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can send javascript back to get the behavior you want.

As the following article shows you have two options:

1. Open in a new window.
2. Use history forward to disable (to the user) the functionality.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/